# fire ajax call in function binding window.scroll only once per conditional check

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7nS5/28/) which detects if targeted `div` is in the viewport. However if I want to fire only one ajax call when the DOM element is in the viewport (instead of multiple times). How could I make this happen?

```
if( isTargetVisble() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
    $('.log').html('<div class="alert alert-success">target element is visible on screen</div>'); // log info
    alert('this is going to be the ajax call')
} else {
    $('.log').html('<div class="alert">target element is not visible on screen</div>'); // log info
}
```

It is firing multiple `alert()` right now as it is binding to `window.scroll`. How could I just fire one when it becomes visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the visible state of the target with a variable.  On each scroll, compare the new value of `isTargetVisble()` with the old.

```
var _alreadyVisible = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){ // bind window scroll event
    if( $('.target').length > 0 ) { // if target element exists in DOM
        if( isTargetVisble() ) { // if target element is visible on screen after DOM loaded
            if(_alreadyVisible){
                //ignore the scroll
            } else {
                //the target just became visible
                _alreadyVisible = true;
                console.log('target became visible')
                $('.log').html('<div class="alert alert-success">target element is visible on screen</div>'); // log info
            }
        } else {
            if(_alreadyVisible){
                //the target was just hidden
                _alreadyVisible = false;
                $('.log').html('<div class="alert">target element is not visible on screen</div>'); // log info
                console.log('target became invisible')
            } else {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonjonash/c7nS5/27/) (bring up the console with F12 and notice how there is only a log when the target changes visibility, not on every scroll)

Comment: Glad to have helped :)