# Call a function when scrolled to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a canvas element that displays an animation, i'd like to call the function "play()", when the canvas element is scrolled to. Encasing a function call in a $(window).on('scroll') event handler, makes it so that whenever my scroll bar is below the element, it recalls the function over and over again. I only want this function to be called once, after the scroll bar reaches a certain threshold.

So ideally it resembles something like:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var top_of_element = $('canvas').offset().top;
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scrollPos > top_of_element) {
        play();
        break; <--cancel function
}
});
```

Comment: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan stated at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394079/fire-ajax-call-in-function-binding-window-scroll-only-once-per-conditional-check) there is no built-in way to do this, but you can keep track of the visibility status of the canvas using a boolean variable. Just set and check it on the corresponding scroll positions and you should be good.